# Is there a list of all known searchable terms for the item shop?

Tags: league-of-legends

When they added the search feature and redid the shop however long ago, they added certain searchable terms for popular items (I believe "tons of damage" pops up trinity force for example). In this patch 3.14, they added "hats" to be a searchable term as well.

What other just-for-fun or short-hand terms can be used to search the shop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several search terms that can be used. I don't know all of them, but here are some from the top of my head.

- Abbreviations. (There's not an abbreviation for every item)

  - RoA (Rod of Ages)
  - IE (Infinity Edge)
  - DFG (Deathfire Grasp)
  - LT (Liandry's Torment)
- Other search terms

  - Spooky Ghosts (Twin Shadows)
  - Tons of Damage (Trinity Force)
  - Pink Ward (Vision Ward)
  - Green ward (Sight Ward)
  - Stark's Fervor (Zeke's Herald)

You can also search for stats, such as Attack Damage or Health Points. For example, searching for "AD HP Armor" would bring up any items that provide Attack Damage, Health, and armor.

Certain items have descriptions. Searching for their description may also bring up the item.

There are probably more search terms and I'll try to add them if I remember any more.

Answer (score 2):

- Liandry's Torment = mask
- Trinity Force = tf
- Phantom Dancer = pd
- trinkets = "red", "blue", "yellow" all work
- Zeke's Herald = starks
- Iceborn Gauntlet = Frozen fist
- Will of the Ancients = Wota
- Zhonya's Hourglass = zhg
- Talisman of Acension = "shurelya", "reverie"
- Lich Bane = LB
- Sightstone = ss
- Sunfire Cape = sfc
- The Black Cleaver = bc
- Doran's Blade/shield/ring = dblade, dshield, dring

Comment: God bless this comment .

Answer (score 1):

Yes another one is "Hat"- It turns up with the Rabadons Deathcap. But this new search term was added recently.

I have not had a chance to test this with the wooglests witchcap (Not available on summoners rift) I will edit when i find out